# How to convert '\t' and '\n' in my json terminal output into something useful?

Tags: jq

I've got some JSON logs from AWS that I'm looking to clean up. They look like this...

```
    {
        "ingestionTime": 1568961184459, 
        "timestamp": 1568961184430, 
        "message": "START RequestId: 0304cf0d-da16-4d01-b4de-da8d528144ac Version: $LATEST\n", 
        "eventId": "34989003600358241981666605756070906630881684882471780352", 
        "logStreamName": "2019/09/20/[$LATEST]71cac888c4a54d11b7e2c97108ad8ba1"
    }, 
    {
        "ingestionTime": 1568961199507, 
        "timestamp": 1568961184432, 
        "message": "2019-09-20T06:33:04.432Z\t0304cf0d-da16-4d01-b4de-da8d528144ac\tAttempting to subscribe John Doe (johndoe@gmail.com) to newsletter...\n", 
        "eventId": "34989003600402843472063667020546010973018230982964936704", 
        "logStreamName": "2019/09/20/[$LATEST]71cac888c4a54d11b7e2c97108ad8ba1"
    },
```

Then I've got them up to this... by using...

```
{
  "ingestionTime": 1568961184459,
  "timestamp": 1568961184430,
  "message": "START RequestId: 0304cf0d-da16-4d01-b4de-da8d528144ac Version: $LATEST\n",
  "eventId": "34989003600358241981666605756070906630881684882471780352",
  "logStreamName": "2019/09/20/[$LATEST]71cac888c4a54d11b7e2c97108ad8ba1"
}
{
  "ingestionTime": 1568961199507,
  "timestamp": 1568961184432,
  "message": "2019-09-20T06:33:04.432Z\t0304cf0d-da16-4d01-b4de-da8d528144ac\tAttempting to subscribe John Doe (johndoe@gmail.com) to newsletter ...\n",
  "eventId": "34989003600402843472063667020546010973018230982964936704",
  "logStreamName": "2019/09/20/[$LATEST]71cac888c4a54d11b7e2c97108ad8ba1"
}
```

This command: `aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name /aws/lambda/$npm_package_name --region us-east-2 | jq '.events[]'`

It would be nice if those `\t`'s were actually tabs, and the `\n` at the end could just be removed. Or separating the message field into several new lines for each new tab.

How might I do this? I don't really know enough bash.

Comment: tr won't do it, because it's 2 characters not one. Have you tried sed?

Comment: I ended up using this combo of jq and tr `aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name /aws/lambda/$npm_package_name --region us-east-2 | jq -r '.events[].message' | tr '\t' '\n'` and that actually worked quite nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jq` output JSON-encoded strings by default.

Would you want the *raw* `message` string, use `-r` or `--raw-output`:

```
jq -r .message file.json
```

(if `file.json` is the JSON document that you are showing).  That would expand the tabs and newlines in that particular string.

Comment: I'm not trying to output to a file, just printing out on the terminal. Adding the -r flag to my current command doesn't change the output at all.

Comment: @Costa No it wouldn't, because, as I said, assumed you were running it on the data that you _showed in the question_. You never show the original data, only what was in the `events` array.  You may want to try `jq -r '.events[].message'` on the output of your `aws` command (but I can for obvious reasons not test that).

Comment: Let me post the original as well then.

Comment: @Costa Note that the JSON you added is a copy (albeit indented) of what was already in the question.

Comment: That's just a sad reflection of my coding skills. I thought I had done something because `jq` had colorized the JSON output : )

Answer (score 1):

Parsing JSON in bash is never recommended, but ....

if you can massage the line:

```
    "message": "newline\n\nword\tword\tword",
```

to become:

```
X_message="newline\n\nword\tword\tword"
```

then you can:

```
$ echo -e "$X_message"
newline

word    word    word
```